# Disabling keys from a T60 thinkpad laptop

Tags: laptop, keyboard, thinkpad

I have two keys in the keyboard that are not useful for me (the page back and page forward by the arrow keys - I press them accidentally - which is NOT fun).

Is there a way to disable these keys ?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I use Ubuntu, so it might be a different answer though. Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'ThinkVantage' -> 'Keyboard Customizer Utility' -> tab 'Key Sensitivity' -> in down left part uncheck 'Enable Browser Keys'

Comment: From ghee22 ==> [Keyboard Customizer Utility for Windows 2000, XP](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-44185) and  [Keyboard Customizer Utility for Windows Vista,7](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-67288) may be of interest